# ShellExecute printing in grayscale only

Tags: vba, printing, shellexecute

I'm using VBA (MSAccess) to print the contents of a folder using ShellExecute.  It works perfectly, except for the small detail of printing in color.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
As LongPtr
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
ShellExecute hwnd, "print", ToPath & "\" & file, 0&, 0&, 0&
```

As I said, everything works exactly as I want it to, except that the print jobs are only printing in grayscale.  I really need this to print in color. Does anyone have any idea of why this is only printing in grayscale?

Comment: It's just not printing in color.  The big bright obnoxious orange field in the middle of my report is now a nice soothing shade of gray.  I can print the file from File Explorer (which is what ShellExecute emulates) and it prints perfectly (obnoxious orange field is obnoxiously orange).

Comment: Never mind. I just found out that my user had Adobe set to print in grayscale.  ("Did you check to make sure that you had Adobe set to print in color?" - "Yes.  I never change that setting."  - "Let me check.." - "Oh wait.. I changed that last week to print a pic in black and white."  <beats head on desk>